# Generics with ArrayAdapters

Tags: java, android, generics, android-arrayadapter

I've run into a problem while trying to create a generic ArrayAdapter.  It probably is related to my limited understanding of generics in Java and was hoping somebody could set me straight.  Basically I have an abstract base adapter class:

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    ....
    private List<T> items;
    ....
    protected abstract List<T> build(JSONArray jsonArray);
    ....
    @Override
    public T getItem(int position)
    {
        return items.get(position);
    }
    ....
}
```

Then I have an adapter that extends this base class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<BaseModel>
{
    ....
    @Override
    protected List<BaseModel> build(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        if (useBaseModel())
        {
            return BaseModel.buildBaseModels(jsonArray); //returns List<BaseModel>
        }
        else
        {
            return SubclassModel.buildSubclassModels(jsonArray); //returns List<SubclassModel>
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

The models are defined as:

```
public class BaseModel{...}

public class SubclassModel extends BaseModel{....}
```

This does not compile, as even though SubclassModel extends BaseModel, Lists of them are not equivalent.  This thread ( [Most efficient way to cast List<SubClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082044/most-efficient-way-to-cast-listsubclass-to-listbaseclass) ) explains as much, and says to use this instead:

```
List<? extends BaseModel>
```

When I change to:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<? extends BaseModel> 
{
    ...
    protected List<? extends BaseModel> build(JSONArray jsonArray)
    ...
 }
```

the errors on the build method go away, but now there is a class level error stating:
getItem(int) in BaseAdapter clashes with getItem(int) in android.widget.ArrayAdapter; attempting to use incompatible return type.

It seems as though getItem should be returning a type ? extends BaseModel, which it is -- can anybody advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm, my Java SDK doesn't even let me compile

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<? extends BaseModel>
```

It expects an unbounded class or interface after the `extends`. But that doesn't matter, a solution to your problem is changing the `BaseAdapter` class if that is an option:

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    ....
    private List<T> items;
    ....
    protected abstract List<? extends T> build(JSONArray jsonArray);
    ....
    @Override
    public T getItem(int position)
    {
        return items.get(position);
    }
}
```

Then

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<BaseModel> 
{
    ...
    protected List<? extends BaseModel> build(JSONArray jsonArray)
    ...
}
```

with the previous code will work.

Edit:

Forgot to explain why your first solution didn't work:

The [Language Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#120403) says

> Subtyping does not extend through generic types: T <: U does not imply that C <: C.

This means although SubclassModel extends BaseModel, this does not imply that List extends List.

Comment: +1 ..Looks like I was typing my answer while you were posting yours :-)

Comment: Similar thoughts, similar error, similar solution, that's scary :)

Comment: Sure enough -- thanks emboss and Kal!  I'll check the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't compile

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<? extends BaseModel>
```

Gives me an error saying "A supertype may not specify a wildcard".

What does work for me is this --

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    private List<? extends T> items;
    protected abstract List<? extends T> build(JSONArray jsonArray);
}
```

and this

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<BaseModel> 
{
    protected List<? extends BaseModel> build(JSONArray jsonArray);
}
```