# Is-a relationship with parameterized references

Tags: java, generics

This has probably been asked before but i haven't been able to find a question.

I would like to understand the underlying reasons why does the following block of code not compile:

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T value;

    public Box(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box<Integer> i = new Box<Integer>(13);

        // does not compile
        Box<Object> o = i;
    }

}
```

Comment: all Integers are Objects, not all Objects are Integers.

Comment: @Stultuske you're right but i don't think that's the problem here...

Comment: Care to elaborate with an answer ? Since Integer i = new Integer(5);
Object o = i; is valid.

Comment: Generics are sometimes weird... because something like `Box<? extends Object> o = i;` does work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to cast List<SubClass> to List<BaseClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082044/most-efficient-way-to-cast-listsubclass-to-listbaseclass)

Comment: @ParkerHalo well this is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to look at it is, let's assume `Box` defined a `void setValue(T val)` method.

```
Box<Object> o = i;
o.setValue("a string");
Integer x = i.getValue(); // ?!
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you cannot cast parameterized types. Check this [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast).

> Typically, you cannot cast to a parameterized type unless it is
> parameterized by unbounded wildcards. For example:
>
> List li = new ArrayList<>(); 
> List  ln = (List) li;  // compile-time error

Hence the line `Box<Object> o = i;` causes compile time error.

Even though while creating `Box` object you have not specified the generic parameter, but using *constructor parameter type* java [Type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) the constructing object's type.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is mentioned in java documentation here (it is similar to Vlad's answer):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

> Let's test your understanding of generics. Is the following code snippet legal?
>
> ```
> List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(); // 1
> List<Object> lo = ls; // 2
> ```
>
> Line 1 is certainly legal. The trickier part of the question is line 2. This boils down to the question: is a List of String a List of Object. Most people instinctively answer, "Sure!"
>
> Well, take a look at the next few lines:
>
> ```
> lo.add(new Object()); // 3
> String s = ls.get(0); // 4: Attempts to assign an Object to a String!
> ```
>
> Here we've aliased ls and lo. Accessing ls, a list of String, through the alias lo, we can insert arbitrary objects into it. As a result ls does not hold just Strings anymore, and when we try and get something out of it, we get a rude surprise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link, it was very informative. However i have decided to accept  vlad's answer since he offered that information first.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any reference to an `Object` reference but when generics kicks in, the exact generic type is matched at compile time. Hence it's not working. If you change to `Box<? extends Object> o = i;` it'll work since the generic type matches the contained type.

Comment: Yup, those question marks are capturing the type somehow. You can't insert any random `Object` into that `Box<? extends Object>` though. It means "some particular subclass of `Object`".