# Java: why is casting possible on wildcard collections?

Tags: java

Suppose we have a class A, and a class B, which inherits from class A.
Let's say we have:

```
Set<A> setOfAs = new HashSet<>();
```

The following casting:

```
((Set<B>) setOfAs)
```

will give us run-time error.

However, if we use wildcard and define the following set:

```
Set<? extends A> setOfAs = new HashSet<>();
```

we have no problem to do the casting:

```
((Set<B>) setOfAs)
```

Why casting a collection of a wildcard is allowed, while casting a collection of "regular" type is forbidden?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to cast List<SubClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082044/most-efficient-way-to-cast-listsubclass-to-listbaseclass)

Comment: "We have no problem" you have an unchecked cast, don't you? A `Set<? extends A>` *could be* a `Set<B>`; but a `Set<A>` can't also be a `Set<B>`.

Comment: *"will give us a run-time error"* — I think you meant a *compile-time* error.

Comment: In short: in the first code snippet, the compiler knows that the code is always wrong (i.e. `Set<A>` can never be cast to a `Set<B>`); in the second code snippet, there could be a situation where this is valid, so the compiler only warns, but does not emit an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> we have no problem to do the casting:

You will have an unchecked cast warning, so it's not really the case that you have no problem; it's just that the compiler can't prove it's definitely wrong, and can't put anything into the bytecode to catch the fact it is wrong at runtime.

A `Set<? extends T>` is a `Set` where it can be assumed that all members can be safely cast to `T` without a `ClassCastException`.

A `Set<? super T>` would be a `Set` where it is known to be safe to add a `T` to it without causing a `ClassCastException` in places relying on the type of elements in the `Set` (I believe the correct technical term for this is *without causing heap pollution*).

A `Set<T>` is the intersection of these two bounded types: you can add instances of `T` to it, and all elements in it are instances of `T`.

By these definitions, a `Set<B>` can act as a `Set<? extends A>`, because anything that can be cast to an `B` can also be cast to `A`.

However, a `Set<A>` cannot act as a `Set<B>`, because it may contain instances of `A` which aren't instances of `B`.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of casting is saying "I know more than you, compiler!" when there's some uncertainty about the actual type of an object.

In the second case, this makes total sense. The compiler knows that `setOfAs` is of type `Set<? extends A>`, which means "a `Set` of an unknown type, and that unknown type extends `A`". There's uncertainty as to what type of `HashSet` it could be. As far as the the compiler is concerned, it *could* be `HashSet<B>`...

```
Set<? extends A> setOfAs = new HashSet<A>();
```

but it also *could* be `HashSet<A>`...

```
Set<? extends A> setOfAs = new HashSet<B>();
```

You, by means of casting, say "No, `setOfAs` *is* a `HashSet<B>`". The compiler goes, "Well, it *could* be that, so I'll trust you". Whether your extra knowledge is actually correct, is a separate matter.

In the first case however, `setofAs` is of type `HashSet<A>`. Since a variable of type `HashSet<A>` can *never* store an object of type `HashSet<B>`, i.e. this does not compile:

```
Set<A> setOfAs = new HashSet<B>();
```

There is no uncertainty about the generic parameter of `Set`. It's gotta be `A`. You, trying to cast to `HashSet<B>`, will only result in the compiler saying "No, it can *never* be that!"